# Basic questions on Picard group (references)

Tags: commutative-algebra, schemes, affine-schemes, ideal-class-group, picard-scheme

I want a reference/explanation for things as follows. For nice enough commutative ring $A$, we have $Pic(A[[x]]) \cong Pic(A)$. Also, I want to know about comparing $Pic(A((x)))$ and $Pic(A)$, for example to know things like $Pic(k[[x_1]]((x_2))) = 1$.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, but I believe that you may want to look for ideas from $K$-theory. There’s a theorem of Grothendieck resembling your claims stating that there is a an isomorphism $K_i(R) \rightarrow K_{i}(R[x])$. Maybe start with ideas from amathew’s blog post on the Quillen-Suslin theorem?

Comment: Well, specifically for something like $k[[x_1]]((x_2))$ I see now that there is no problem; $k[[x_1]]$ is a PID and therefore $k[[x_1]][[x_2]]$ is a UFD, and therefore its localization $k[[x_1]]((x_2))$ is a UFD, and so it has a trivial Picard group.